# Opening a new form with specific tab

Tags: delphi, vcl

I was hoping that something like this should work:

```
Form2.Show();
Form1.Hide();
Form2.PageControl1.ActivePage := TabSheet1;
```

The thing is that I have a multiple buttons (in the first form), and I want for each one of them to open the new form in a specific tab of the PageControl.

Error: `Undeclared identifier: 'TabSheet1'`

Comment: I regularly use each of these commands with no issues. So what exactly is your problem? I think that you need to give a bit more than this, preferably a small sample program that shows your issue. Also please clarify whether it is Firemonkey or VCL and which version of Delphi you are using.

Comment: Its VCL. It says that `Undeclared identifier: 'TabSheet1'` - Delphi 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message shows that TabSheet1 is not defined - and that is probably (although don't show us the full code) because you are outside the parent object, so you need the line

```
Form2.PageControl1.ActivePage := Form2.TabSheet1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dsm's answer is the correct answer to the question asked.

But from a design perspective, while that will work fine, it does require the calling code to have knowledge of Form2's internals, which is not good class encapsulation.  I would instead add a data member to `Form2` to indicate the desired page to display in the Form's `OnShow` event, and then set that member before calling `Show()`, eg:

```
type
  TWhichTab = (wtNone, wtTab1, wtTab2, ...);

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    ...
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  public
    ...
    InitialTab: TWhichTab;
  end;

  procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := Ord(InitialTab)-1;
  end;
```

```
Form2.InitialTab := wtTab2;
Form2.Show();
Form1.Hide();
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, although I would take it a stage further and refer to what is being displayed rather which tab, because how the  information is displayed should be down to the visual object. Tabs might be reordered for instance 6 month down the line.